# AJAX скрипт не дает другому JS (яндекс.карты) выполнится

Tags: javascript

Есть  стандартный AJAX скрипт отправки данных на контроллер(PHP)далее в БД(MySQL) .Данные отправляются с формы (HTML). В HTML разметке после формы идет стандартный скрипт яндекс.карты, который не отображается. Если отключить AJAX карта отображается, но при работе скрипта карта не видна. В чем проблемы, не могу понять?

```
function postMessage() { 
 var formData = new FormData(document.forms.name_form);
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //создаем объект
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { //проверяем ответ на ошибки 
            // если норм то выводим

            document.getElementById("result_output").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
        else
        {
            // если нет сообщаем об ошибке
            document.getElementById("result_output").innerHTML = "Error";
        }   
    };
 xhr.open("POST", "/controller.php"); // post запрос на конкретный контроллер
 xhr.send(formData); //отпраляем данные на контроллер
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Задачу решил сам. Оказалось все просто. В HTML разметке необходимо указать id.

```
<input type="button" id="btn_form" class="btn_order" value="Отправить заявку на участие"/>
```

А в скрипт подправить вот так

```
document.getElementById('btn_form').onclick = function() { 
 var formData = new FormData(document.forms.name_form);
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //создаем объект
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { //проверяем ответ на ошибки 
            // если норм то выводим

            document.getElementById("result_output").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
        else
        {
            // если нет сообщаем об ошибке
            document.getElementById("result_output").innerHTML = "Error";
        }   
    };
 xhr.open("POST", "/controller.php"); // post запрос на конкретный контроллер
 xhr.send(formData); //отпраляем данные на контроллер
```

}

Теперь нет никакого конфликта.

Comment: Ваша проблема была в том, что не стоило называть свою функцию [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).